# How to understand keras features?

Tags: python, numpy, keras, classification

I have extracted features from a set of images. Keras features have provided the shape `(X, 7, 7, 512)` where X is the number of images.

I can see that there are 512 layers. Each layer is (7, 7). I need to access each of the 49 elements in each layer and take their average. But I am having trouble understanding how to access the elements when it is in the format mentioned above.

How can I go about doing this? Can someone help me gain clarity?

Comment: `np.mean(output, axis=(1, 2))`?

Comment: When I do this, how can I verify that it is indeed calculating the mean of the 49 elements in each layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the mean of each layer using [`np.mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) with specified axes, as `np.mean(axis=(1, 2))`. To make sure this is doing what you want, you can test a couple layers:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randn(10, 7, 7, 512)

layer_means = np.mean(data, axis=(1, 2))
print(layer_means[0, 0], np.mean(data[0, :, :, 0]))
print(layer_means[2, 6], np.mean(data[2, :, :, 6]))
```